# Netbeans and Xdebug in Linux

Tags: linux, netbeans, xdebug

I have installed Xdebug, and I can confirm from `phpinfo()` that it is correctly installed. I have taken all the steps given in all of the sites that come up with I `google` "netbeans xdebug install, etc".

It still does not work in Netbeans.
Is there any advice that someone can offer?

Here is my php.ini debug section...

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it doesn't work"? Can u explain what's happening exactly when you press debug project?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. It does nothing, and gives me the dialog explaining that it could not connect to xdebug when I stop.

Comment: When you press _"Debug Project"_ does it say at the bottom on Netbeans: _"Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)"_ and keeps waiting for connection till it timeout?

Comment: Well I always configured xdebug using the Linux tutorial on [the netbeans website](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug#How_to_on_Linux). Maybe you generated a corrupted **xdebug.so** ?! Have you confirmed that it actually exists at `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so` ?!

Comment: Well, I thought we were on to something. The second php.ini (in the apache2 dir) - I configured there as well, but same result.

Comment: Did you check the Debugger port? This is the port that XDebug uses, as set in php.ini. By default it is port 9000. The port number in the debugger tab in Netbeans' PHP options must be the same as the debugger port you set in php.ini.

Comment: BTW I know this is going to sound stupid, but did you restart Apache and PHP after changing the php.ini? coz without restart things won't be affected :D

Comment: Checked port, restarted apache... Xdebug is part of Zend Modules (php -m) - everything every web site has said to do. It has to be something simple... some setting I am missing. I have made this work on Windows before.

Comment: Adding bounty! Hoping to get an answer. I have tried everything I know how to try.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since the information available to me is very sparse, I have to describe the settings in more detail.

**Netbeans and xdebug settings.**

> Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin

What ought to be installed.

[image]

[image]

**Global settings:**

> Tools -- Options

[image]

[image]

**PHP settings:**

With **phpinfo()** you get.. see below image.

[image]

Only **one** php.ini is important !  Look at **Loaded Configuration File**
If you wrote a xdebug entry into another "php.ini" file be sure to **clear all these entries** again. ( xdebug ONLY in one php.ini ). Look also at **Additional .ini files parsed**. We come to this later.

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

[image]

**Additional .ini files parsed**.
Add or controlling, only the first line must be the same as in the "php.ini".( Without " " )

[image]

Make sure that the file is really there!

[image]

Make sure that the **session.save_path** is really there!

[image]

Control the **xdebug** version that should be equal to or greater.( Matching PHP Version-5.3.10-1 ). If everything was done as described in this answer, and it does not work, then it is with great probability of an **incorrect or defective** "xdebug.so".

[image]

**Create a new Php Project:**

[image]

**Project Properties:**
Sources
In our test program, **it is important** the Project Folder and Source Folder are **exactly alike**!

[image]

Run Configuration

[image]

[image]

**Start Debug:** -- press Debug button

[image]

The default Browser opens and remains at **Connecting ..** stand while Netbeans in debug mode is.
(If Netbeans do not open a Browser or can not connect, go back to **Advanced Web Configuration** and select **Do Not Open Web Browser**. Close an reopen the browser and type the URL as seen below)

[image]

Go through your code. You will see only something in the browser when you're done with the debugging. Don't forget to press the **Stop Button** [image] . If you forget this xdebug is running on.

**Done:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the last step, one can run this in the terminal to check that everything needed is installed (otherwise, it will be installed): `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-suphp apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork libapache2-mod-php5 apache2-utils php5-xdebug php5-cli php5-common libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cgi php5`

Answer (score 6):

Try using `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` instead of `xdebug.remote_host` to avoid security issues

In fact,

```
zend_extension=path/to/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

Must be enough.

Make sure that `project properties->run configuration->advanced->do not open web browser` option **is NOT selected** (in netbeans project config).

Also, check **project url** value in **run configuration**

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't with the configuration of xdebug itself, but how I had NetBeans configured. It was a simple error... basically I was having NetBeans navigate to my /var/www/Application directory, which I hadn't actually set up yet.

Thanks to everyone for their help. I learned a lot about how xdebug works!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the remote port is set to 9000 in the xdebug.ini file, mine was set to 8000 and once I changed it, xdebug worked immediately.