# Netbeans, xdebug : start debugging from browser

Tags: php, debugging, browser, netbeans, xdebug

I have following problem about debugging `PHP files` in `Netbeans` using `xdebug`:
when I debug directly `PHP file` everything works OK.

BUT:

If I debug whole file (starts in `index.html`) and after I click submit button which execute my `PHP file`, where is the breakpoint, It doesn't work. 
I wanna put breakpoint to `PHP file` to see what info I've received from my form in `HTML` page.

I want to stop program just after those 2 variables, sent through ajax:

```
$username = $_REQUEST["username"];
$password = $_REQUEST["password"];
```

Is it even possible?. Thank you!

Comment: Can you indicate how are you trying it? Once you started the debug session in the browser it'll continue to apply until the browser session is lost. Perhaps your code is not entering the point you it should be stopping, try manual debugging if you're in doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Netbeans settings [look at my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13021858/1322642) it's for linux but may help you.

**In your index.html replace your** `action=` with

```
<form action="yourphpfile.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug" method="post" name="FormName">
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to modify your form code to enable debugging, as suggested by another answer here.

1. Go to Project Properties > Run Configuration > Advanced... > Debug URL and check "Do not open web browser".
2. Do not set the Host under Debugger Proxy.
3. Save these settings.
4. In the project window, go to Debug > Debug Project (Ctrl-F5).  This starts listening for debug connections. No browser is started, but you'll see "Waiting for connection..." in your status bar (bottom).
5. Install one of the plug-ins for your browser listed over at the 3rd step of [Starting the Debugger](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote).
6. Enable debugging with the browser plug-in you just installed.
7. Hit the URL you'd like to debug, fill out the form, and submit it.

This answer was partially sourced from [Launch XDebug in Netbeans on an external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531391/launch-xdebug-in-netbeans-on-an-external-request).