# xdebug with IIS and netbeans

Tags: php, iis, netbeans

I'm trying to set up xdebug. I'm using netbeans and IIS. My php.ini file contains:

```
 [XDebug]
 zend_extension = "C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11-nts-x86_64.dll"
 xdebug.remote_autostart=on
 xdebug.remote_enable=on
 xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
 xdebug.remote_host=192.168.8.98
 xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
 xdebug.remote_port=9000
 xdebug.remote_mode=req
 xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
 xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on
 xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t
```

(although I've tried lots of combinations of the above!).

I'm getting the message

```
    'Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)'
```

in netbeans when I try and start debugging.
My question is what should I see in infophp? All I see about debugging is:-

```
**Configure Command**   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
**Debug Build** no
**report_zend_debug**   On  On
**Loaded plugins**  mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
**com_debug**   0

**_COOKIE["XDEBUG_SESSION"]**   XDEBUG_ECLIPSE
**_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"]**  XDEBUG_SESSION=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE
```

It deosn't seem right to me - especially the XDEBUG_ECLIPSE references but I'm not sure where these are set.

Comment: I don't think you need to specify a remote host if you're using remote connect back.

Comment: Try set `xdebug.remote_host=192.168.8.98` to `xdebug.remote_host=localhost` [Look at my answer here and the link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13405417/1322642).

Comment: I've tried using 'localhost' as the remote_host and not remote_host but to no avail.

Comment: My real question is shouldn't I seem some sign of the extension with phpinfo() - because I don't?

Answer (score 1):

Result!

I replaced [Xdebug] with [Zend] and now I'm getting an xdebug section of my phpinfo() like I was expecting.