# Debugging with Xdebug and Netbeans on Fedora

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug, fedora

How do I install Xdebug on a Fedora 17 OS in order to use it with netbeans 7.3(in beta)?

Comment: Perhaps similar? Ubuntu version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869189/netbeans-and-xdebug-in-linux/13021858#13021858

Comment: If you install a VPN service, sometimes port 9000 is occupied. Then you need to switch to e.g. 9009 - a common problem on Fedora.(FYI)

Comment: I've moved the solution from the question into your answer - hopefully that's fixed things up now so it'll stop getting flagged. Thanks for sharing what you found.

Comment: Thanks you for fixing my novice mess xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install Xdebug:

> sudo yum install php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64

Add this lines to php.ini at the end of `/etc/php.ini`

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Add the same lines to `/etc/php-zts.d/xdebug.ini`:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Allow port for Xdebug

```
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 9000
```

Now find your netbeans.conf file in your system:

```
sudo find / -name netbeans.conf
```

Now, open up the file and add the text “-J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.level=400″ in netbeans_default_options so that the line looks somewhat like this:

> netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m
>   -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dsun.awt.disableMixing=true -J-Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes -J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.level=400"

Restart both NetBeans IDE and apache:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: Adding option to netbeans conf make it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Configure php.ini for xDebug
Use: output_buffering = Off
Comment out any lines that configures output_buffering such as output_buffering = 4096
Add the following to /etc/php.ini
zend_extension=”/usr/lib/php5/…../xdebug.so”
[xdebug]
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = true
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
;xdebug.remote_mode=”req”
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = “/tmp/”
xdebug.idekey=”netbeans-xdebug”
```