# Xdebug, Vagrant, UBUNTU, and Netbeans integration

Tags: php, netbeans, vagrant, xdebug, remote-debugging

Netbeans, keep giving {remote xdebug waiting for connection}
I am using vagrant UBUNTU BOX
On Server
[xdebug]

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.cli_color = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.44.1
xdebug.var_display_max_children=512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=20
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/vagrant"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
```

I can ping 192.168.44.1 from my local machine

[Netbeans]
Project advanced configuration:

```
Host: 192.168.44.1 Port: 9000
```

Debugging configuration:

```
Debugger Port: 9000
SessiinID: xdebug
```

So my problem is, each time i add a break point and run debug file, it keep trying to connect to Host Xdebug

Any suggestions!

Comment: can you debug on computer 192.168.44.1 not via local machine ? My answer here is a bit outdated but the steps are similar. [xdebug netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13021858/1322642)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and found this article to help me out: http://pietervogelaar.nl/php-xdebug-netbeans-vagrant

At the bottom of the article this is the part that helped me out:

> Xdebug from the command line inside a (Vagrant) virtual machine If you want to use Xdebug with command line scripts or phpunit inside the
>   virtual machine, that still won’t work with the settings defined up
>   till now. Because Xdebug won’t find a remote host to connect back to.
>
> Run the following command inside the virtual machine:
>
> ```
> netstat -rn
> ```
>
> You will probably see something like:
>
> ```
> Kernel IP routing table
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
> 0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
> 0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
> 10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
> 192.168.33.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
> ```
>
> This tells us that the IP address that Xdebug must connect to is
>   10.0.2.2. So with the following example command it should work:
>
> ```
>  php -d xdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2 phpunit -c module/Application/test
> ```